# Is this a good way to implement idle timeout in an MVC5 IdentityServer Client application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, session-cookies, identityserver4

I have a requirement to timeout the user after 20 minutes following the last request. I got myself tied up in all kinds of knots trying to do this using cookie and id_token lifetimes and eventually decided I couldn't make this work. So instead I decided to just use a 20 minute id_token and set the authentication cookie with `SlidingExpiration = true` and no `ExpireTimeSpan` (i.e. it will live until the end of the user session). I then implemented an authentication filter to store a timeout value in the Session cookie, then log the user out when too much time has passed since the previous request (this will result in the user being redirected to the Identity Server login page).

Once I'm satisfied with it I plan to register it as a global filter.

I plan to have a client side script provide a timeout warning before refreshing the page after 20 minutes (causing a round trip to the server, resulting in the authentication filter below executing and therefore user logout). I didn't want to rely on the client side script to enforce the logout (hence the use of an authentication filter which will run whenever the user requests a page).

Can you see anything wrong with this approach and/or offer a better solution?

```cs
    public class CheckSessionTimeoutAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute, IAuthenticationFilter
    {
        public void OnAuthentication(AuthenticationContext filterContext)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("OnAuthentication");
            var currentContext = HttpContext.Current;
            int idleTimeoutMins = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["IdleTimeoutMins"].ParseInt();
            if (currentContext.Session["Timeout"] == null)
            {
                currentContext.Session["Timeout"] = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(idleTimeoutMins);
            }
            else
            {
                var timeout = Convert.ToDateTime(HttpContext.Current.Session["Timeout"]);
                var now = DateTime.Now;
                if (Convert.ToDateTime(HttpContext.Current.Session["Timeout"]) < DateTime.Now)
                {
                    // timeout expired so log out and reject authentication request
                    currentContext.Session.Abandon();
                    currentContext.Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut();
                    filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
                }
                else
                {
                    currentContext.Session["Timeout"] = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(idleTimeoutMins);
                }
            }
        }

        public void OnAuthenticationChallenge(AuthenticationChallengeContext filterContext)
        {
            // Nothing here
        }
    }
```

Edit 20191204: Changed from use of ActionFilter to IAuthenticationFilter

Comment: You have some reading to do. You need to understand the lifetime of cookie, that server code only executes when a request come in, that when a cookie is expired, a logout is not necessary as expired cookie is never sent by browser or even if it expires on the way, server identity server will consider user as unauthenticated automatically and so on.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Are you able to explain what is wrong with my approach and/or explain a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

I found a slightly better way, but it's still a bit of a hack. I now use the Session cookie's timeout property, set to 20 minutes in the web.config

It still feels as though this ought to be done using the authentication cookie instead, but I've tried every combination of `SlidingExpiration`, `ExpireTimeSpan`, `UseTokenLifeTime` and the IdentityServer's IdentityTokenLifetime setting that I can think of and can't get any of it to work as intended.

If anyone can suggest improvements or explain a better way to implement idle timeout then please do!

```cs
public void OnAuthentication(AuthenticationContext filterContext)
{
    var currentContext = HttpContext.Current;
    // If this is a new Session cookie the user has either not logged in yet
    // , or the Session cookie expired and was replaced with a new one.
    if (currentContext.Session.IsNewSession)
    { 
        if (Authorization.IsAuthenticated) 
        {
            // If Session is new but they're authenticated it's because their session cookie 
            // expired, so log them out.
            currentContext.Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut();
        }
        // Ensure there is a Session cookie so that it's not new on subsequent requests
        currentContext.Session["SessionStart"] = DateTime.Now;
        filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
    }
}
```